# What is the source of the discrepancy in Java versions: Java 6 (in Terminal, Eclipse) and Java 7 (in Java Control panel)?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse complains: `JRE version is 1.6.0; version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run Google Plugin for Eclipse`.

[image: Eclipse and JRE]

In the Terminal, java concurs:

```
> java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

But in System Preferences \ Java \ the Java Control Panel says `Your system has the recommended version of Java: Java 7 Update 51`

[image: Java Control Panel]

and points to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

[image: SystemPrefs]

Eclipse preferences show that the installed JRE is at:
    /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

[image: EclipsePrefs]

To point Eclipse to Java 7 (1.7.0), it's enough to change the preference:

[image: New Java version to Eclipse]

What is the source of the discrepancy in Java versions? Is this an instance of having different PATHs between the command-line Mac and the windowed-Mac?

**Edit**

If I edit `/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` by adding

```
-vm
"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java"
```

Eclipse refuses to start.

[image: JRE-or-JDK-must-be-available]

And yet this is indeed 1.7:

```
> "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: From the error dialog it seems that it's not getting the full path; see how the dialog stops at `.../Home` but the full path is `.../Home/bin/java`

Comment: I tried all variations. Both Home/bin/java and just Home. With quotation marks (to shield the space) and with a backslash escape.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be certain of the JVM that is used to run Eclipse, you need to specify it in your `eclipse.ini` file, according to [these instructions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Comment: I'm not concerned what JVM Eclipse is running on, only for the (recent) Google plugin to run, and the latter requires JRE 1.7. In any case, this problem is solved, as I mention. What is the source of the discrepancy between the command-line and the windowed environment?

Comment: Since you want to use a plugin that requires a specific JRE, doesn't that mean that you *are* concerned about what JVM Eclipse is run in? Also, changing the "Installed JREs" preferences in Eclipse *does not* affect the JRE that is used to run Eclipse itself; those preferences are only for applications that you run from Eclipse. To affect the JVM that runs Eclipse itself you must do so external to Eclipse (eg, eclipse.ini or OS path, etc.)

Comment: I don't know why you'd see a difference between command-line and "windowed." On my Mac I only ever launch Eclipse from a desktop shortcut. But I do know that OS X's management of JVMs is quite a mess and quite confusing.

Comment: let's backtrack then.. Is running Eclipse itself under 1.7 sufficient to know that the Google plugin will also run under 1.7?

Comment: Yes. All Eclipse plugins run in the Eclipse Platform "container" and thus on the same JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this update might fix your problem:

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572